# Can I use an SQL database(mysql) as devdatabaseType and NoSQL(mongodb) as prodDatabaseType in jhipster

Tags: mongodb, jhipster

I needed information regarding the feasibility to select an sql db for dev database and nosql db for prod database.

While executing jhipster on cli, once we select mongodb as database type, it doesn't ask for dev type and prod type and the generated .yo-rc.json file contains the information as

"databaseType": "mongodb",
"devDatabaseType": "mongodb",
"prodDatabaseType": "mongodb",

So is it possible to make alterations as per my requirement by changing the .yo-rc.json values manually and then generate the code by jhipster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't do that because it does not use same technology stack, it would not make sense. Generated source code would not be compatible.